# Singleton. Объявление оператора присваивания закрытым

Tags: c++, классы, singleton

Здравствуйте, начал разбираться в паттернах, и возник вопрос касательно паттерна singleton. Зачем объявлять оператор присваивания закрытым в классе singleton? Чтобы нельзя было присвоить объект класса singleton другому объекту, в результате получилось бы 2 объекта класса singleton, что и нельзя допускать. Это основная причина или есть еще более важные?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Именно. Смысл синглтона - один, и только один. Разреши присваивание, копирование - и все. В современном С++ можно не делать закрытым, а объявить как удаленный (`= delete`).

"100 фертингов - это 100 фертингов, а забери хоть сантик - и это уже не 100 фертингов" (с) Незнайка на Луне :-)

Comment: Harry, как с вами можно связаться???

Comment: А зачем? :) Ну, оставьте свой адрес, я напишу.